# Maple can't solve when matrices are included.

Tags: maple

Anyone know why Maple can't solve this equation?
[image]

It's childsplay for Ti-Nspire, so I'm wondering why Maple can't do this. Does it have something to do with the matrices?

Comment: There is no any equation to solve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
A1:=<1,1|-1,2>:
A2:=<1,2|-1,1>:
A3:=<1,2|-1,2>:

solve(Equate(t*A1+s*A2+u*A3,<0,0|0,0>));

         {s = 0, t = 0, u = 0}
```

Answer (score 0):

It works

```
with(linalg):
A1:=matrix([[1,-1],[1,2]]);
A2:=matrix([[1,-1],[2,1]]);
A3:=matrix([[1,-1],[2,2]]);
S:=matadd(matadd(A1,A2,t,s),A1,1,u);
solve(convert(S,set),{t,s,u});
```

Comment: linalg is almost never the right answer.  Your call to convert should work on Matrix too.